# JHipster Application Generation Stuck

Tags: java, node.js, jhipster

I am following the steps from http://www.jhipster.tech/installation/ to install JHipster using the steps for "npm" and creatingan application but get stuck at the following step. Nothing happens after this (not even any errors)

```
$>jhipster
....
....
....
         favicon.ico    5.43 kB          [emitted]
                                              robots.txt  239 bytes          [emitted]
                                              index.html    1.13 kB          [emitted]
    [./node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss
    5.22 kB {3} [built]
           [] -> factory:437ms building:14601ms = 15038ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/admin/admin.module.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/admin.module.ts 2.78 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:62ms building:515ms dependencies:141ms = 718ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/app.constants.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.constants.ts 651 bytes {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:624ms building:156ms = 780ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts 599 bytes {2} [built]
            factory:546ms building:7940ms = 8486ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts 2.87 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:62ms building:172ms = 234ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/prod.config.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/prod.config.ts 391 bytes {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:94ms building:171ms dependencies:640ms = 905ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/uib-pagination.config.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/config/uib-pagination.config.ts 1.57 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:62ms building:281ms dependencies:343ms = 686ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/interceptor/http.provider.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/blocks/interceptor/http.provider.ts 1.6 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:62ms building:453ms dependencies:203ms = 718ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/entities/entity.module.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/entities/entity.module.ts 1.36 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:62ms building:546ms dependencies:63ms = 671ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.module.ts 1.56 kB {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:62ms building:390ms dependencies:1560ms = 2012ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/index.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/index.ts 618 bytes {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:640ms building:124ms = 764ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts 2.63 kB {1} [built]
            factory:46ms building:8362ms = 8408ms
    [./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts] ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts 284 bytes {2} [built]
           [] -> factory:47ms building:234ms = 281ms
    [./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss] ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss 1.38 kB {3} [built]
            factory:546ms building:62ms = 608ms
    [./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp] ./src/main/webapp/manifest.webapp 61 bytes {1} [built]
           [] -> factory:562ms dependencies:0ms building:1216ms = 1778ms
        + 896 hidden modules
```

I am using Win 7 (x64), Node 8.9.1, npm 5.5.1 Jhipster 4.10.2, and Java 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 is no longer supported by JHipster.
Anyway you can try to look at your system icon tray. There could be a pending notification and if you click on it, it will unblock your app build.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This has helped in getting the build done but now i have another problem. The application runs properly without any errors but i get a blank page at localhost:8080. Tried running yarn and it says that the dependencies have been resolved properly but the blank page persists. I will create a separate thread for this issue.